# CKRecord set parent error 4097

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to set a parent on a CKRecord. Basically, a reminder is the child of a list. The list already exists on the server.

```
let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Reminder", recordID: recordID)
let listID = CKRecordID(recordName: listName, zoneID: listZoneID)
record["title"] = "Test TODO"
record.setParent(listID)
let modifyRecordsOp = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave:[record], recordsToDelete:nil)
modifyRecordsOp.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (_, _, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
         print(error)
         return
    }
}
```

Every time I do this, I get the following error:
[LogFacilityCK] Got a connection error for operation 28174DD7CAF85542: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.cloudd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.cloudd}

If I remove the setParent line, then the record is created successfully on the server. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the listID record is not yet saved to the cloud, therefore the cloud cannot set `listID` as the parent of `record`. Try saving both newly created records:

```
let modifyRecordsOp = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave:[record, listID], recordsToDelete:nil)
```